# Sharepoint Document Library not receiving emails

Tags: sharepoint, document-management

I have created a SharePoint document library which has email enabled. However, when I send email to the designated email address, I don't receive the email & attachment in the list. I have done some R&D and I've found out that in order to receive email from anywhere I have to expose my DNS of the SharePoint site to the outside world. Now I don't know whether it applies to the email address designated to me in the Active directory profile as well (my company domain email address). How to test that this email reception is working in the document library? I have tried sending an email from the SharePoint site and it works fine so the SMTP settings are correctly done.

Comment: If you only want to receive messages sent internally, then you only need to set up an internal MX record so that your mail servers know where to deliver messages sent to the domain you select.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to make sure that you have an MX record somewhere in DNS so that a mail server can deliver to the sharepoint server.  This could be a public DNS record, or internal, depending on your needs.

To test whether you have set up Sharepoint and the local SMTP server properly try the following:

View the folder you configured the smtp server to deliver to (C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Drop for example) - you will watch this to see if messages are delivered.

Then open a telnet session to the sharepoint server on port 25.  Via this you can "send" a test message directly to the smtp server using the address of your Document Library.

```
telnet spserver.localdomain.local 25
ehlo test.com
MAIL FROM: <test@test.com>
RCPT TO: <doclib@spserver.localdomain.local>
DATA
Subject: Test Message
This is a test message
.
```

If you have your smtp server configured correctly, and you see a message saying the message was queued after typing the above, then you should see a file appear in the folder you are watching.

If Sharepoint is configured to check this folder correctly, after a few minutes you should see the message disappear from the folder and appear in the Document Library.

The only time I have seen messages disappear from the drop folder, and *not* appear in the Doc Library, it has been when sending messages with nothing in the body.  Sharepoint seems to discard these, even if there is an attachment.

I also had issues where Sharepoint was creating contacts in AD with the wrong email address - check these are created as you would expect otherwise Exchange may discard mail coming in from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this:

e.g. send email from abc@gmail.com (or abc@hotmail.com etc) to youremail@yourlocaldomain.com?

If this is so that is not possible if "yourdomain" is just an intranet within your organization.